# Qt: iterator of a vector in a QMap

Tags: c++, qt, vector, iterator, qmap

I am working with Qt and OpenCV and I would like to create an iterator with `std::vector <cv::Rect_<int>>` to have access to all cv::Rect_.
This vector is part of a `QMap < int, std::vector <cv::Rect_<int>> > _facesframe;`

So this is how I am trying to have access to these vectors:

```
                foreach (unsigned int frame , _imageGItem->_faceSampler._facesframe.keys() )
                {
                    std::vector <cv::Rect_<int>>::const_iterator it = _imageGItem->_faceSampler._facesframe.value(frame).begin();
                    if( it != _imageGItem->_faceSampler._facesframe.value(frame).end())
                    {
                        qDebug()<<"here";
                    }

                }
```

But the program crashes at the line `if...` because of an incompatible iterator.

Does someone know how to reach all `cv::Rect_<int>` of a `QMap < int, std::vector <cv::Rect_<int>> >` please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are comparing iterators to different vectors.

```
const T QMap::value(const Key & key, const T & defaultValue = T()) const
```

Vector is returned by value, so this is copied.

You should use

```
T & QMap::operator[](const Key & key)
```

to correct this:

```
foreach (unsigned int frame , _imageGItem->_faceSampler._facesframe.keys() )
  {
    std::vector <cv::Rect_<int>>::const_iterator it =
                       _imageGItem->_faceSampler._facesframe[frame].begin();
    if( it != _imageGItem->_faceSampler._facesframe[frame].end())
      {
        qDebug()<<"here";
      }

  }
```

or (less efficient bacause of 1 copy being made):

```
std::vector <cv::Rect_<int>> v =   // this will copy
                            _imageGItem->_faceSampler._facesframe.value(frame);
std::vector <cv::Rect_<int>>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
if( it != v.end())
  {
    qDebug()<<"here";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you both options you proposed work. I used you second option.

Answer (score 1):

`QMap::value` returns by *value.* Which means it's returning a *copy* of the vector, and of course your iterator points to a different vector (a different copy). Change it to use the non-const version `operator[]` instead (as the `const` version of that *also* returns by value). Or just use `std::map`, which offers a much better interface in this regard.

Comment: Thank you as also said @piotruś you are right `operator[]` also works.

Comment: Angew was first about operator[], I was first about second option and first providing answer with explanation in general